# innosetup - capturing events from wizard page controls

Tags: onclick, radio-button, inno-setup, disabled-control

I have seen answers for capturing events from user-created controls on wizard pages, but how do you do it for controls created as a result of a call to CreateInputOptionPage?

For example:

```
InputOptionPage := CreateInputOptionPage (wpWelcome,
  'Options', 
  'Select your option',
  'Please choose from one of the three options below:'
  True, False);

InputOptionPage.Add ('Option 1') ;
InputOptionPage.Add ('Option 2') ;
InputOptionPage.Add ('Option 3') ;
```

will create an option page with a radio group on it.  I don't intend selecting any of the options by default and want to force the user to do so.  As a visual clue I want to gray out the "Next" button while none are selected.

How do I add an `OnClick` handler for the radio buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not directly the same question, the answer I just provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851785/hook-standard-inno-setup-checkbox/5863058#5863058) shows how to do this for a Check Box but it's identical for a radio box.

Answer (score 2):

Short extract from Robert Love's answer:

```
procedure YourControlClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox('yep', mbError, 0);
end;

YourControl.OnClick := @YourControlClick;
```

I.e. everything is similar to usual Delphi style except for `@` symbol. Omitting it results in confusing "Invalid number of parameters" error during compile.